# Is this similar to the ternary operator in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I saw this in some vb.net source code:

```
Dim sTest As String = "" & drTest("column")
```

I was told that if drTest("column") is nothing, then sTest will be assigned "", so it is in effect doing:

```
Dim sTest As String = If("",Nothing,drTest("column"))
```

What is the downside of doing it the first way I showed?

What is the difference between using If and IIf?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`If` *is* the ternary conditional operator.

> What is the difference between using If and IIf?

`IIf` is an ordinary function that is implemented approximately as follows:

```
Function If(Of T)(condition As Boolean, ifTrue As T, ifFalse As T)
    If condition Then Return ifTrue
    Return ifFalse
End Function
```

This means that no matter the value of `condition`, both its other arguments are always evaluated. This doesn’t happen with the `If` operator.

But your code is actually doing something completely different:

```
Dim sTest As String = If("",Nothing,drTest("column"))
```

This makes no sense and shouldn’t even compile (or at least give a warning). Your first code is fine – it works always and there is no downside. It’s not clear what the second code is even trying to achieve.

Comment: If you wanted to approximate the logic using If, you'd be looking for something more like the following: `If(drTest("column") Is Nothing, "", drTest("column"))`

Comment: Coming from a c# background, I am a little confused with the syntax?  What does Of T mean?  As far as the code for my If, I put a ternary operation into a c# to vb.net converter and it generated that.

Comment: @Xaisoft `(Of T)` is VB’s way of writing a generic Parameter, i.e. it’s equivalent to `<T>`. As for your code, it wouldn’t make sense in C# either, and it would most certainly not compile: `"" ? null : drTest("column")` is not valid C#.

Comment: @Xiasoft: `(Of T)` is equivalent to `<T>` in C#; it's indicating that the function takes a generic type argument named `T`. @Ian: Though your version will have the side effect of calling `drTest("column")` twice, which may be undesirable. The first version works because the `&` concatenation operator in VB.NET treats null references (on either side of the operator) as empty strings.

Comment: I changed it to the way Ian Puglsey had it.  Is the Is Nothing part necessary?

Comment: @Xaisoft It is (as in C#!) but this is really redundant because of what Adam said: string concatenation with `null` values works anyway, no need to change it.

Comment: After looking at some MSDN documentation, it is more clear to me now.  Could I also do this:  If(drTest("column"),"").  According to this, drTest("column") would return whatever is contained in it as long as it is nothing, but if it is nothing, it would return an empty string.

Comment: @Xaisoft In response to your last comment, yes, you could do that and it’s superior to the ternary version of the operator (it corresponds to C#’s null coalesce operator, `??`). I totally forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

While @Konrad Rudolph's answered your specific question, I'd like to continue where he left off saying:

> This makes no sense and shouldn’t even
>   compile (or at least give a warning).
>   Your first code is fine – it works
>   always and there is no downside. It’s
>   not clear what the second code is even
>   trying to achieve.

He's right in that you shouldn't even be doing what your second line is suggesting.  The simple answer that achieves the effect you are trying for, would be to use `TryCast` instead.  You are only assigning a non-empty string value when `drTest("column")` contains a value.  Since that's the case, why not do:

```
Dim sTest As String = TryCast(drTest("column"), String)
```

This way you get your value if the `TryCast` succeeds, otherwise you get `Nothing`.

Now since `TryCast` returns `Nothing` and since your example showed that you wanted to assign `""`, you might not want to go this route, as it can lead into the frustration of handling String Nothingness vs "" / String.Empty. You could use the `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` method if you want, but that requires you to pass in your string as a parameter and, to me, that clunks up your code.  Alternatively, you could create your own StringExtensions Module like I have and use the extensions to check Nothingness and Emptiness:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module StringExtensions

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function IsNullOrEmpty(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
        Return s Is Nothing OrElse s.Trim.Length.Equals(0)
    End Function

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function IsNotNullOrEmpty(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
        Return s IsNot Nothing AndAlso s.Trim.Length > 0
    End Function

End Module
```

Then to achieve your effect of setting `""` with respect to Nothingness, one could use the combination of the `TryCast` and my StringExtensions methods to do:

**With ternary If**

```
Dim sColumn1 As String = TryCast(drTest("column1"), String)
Dim sColumn2 As String = TryCast(drTest("column2"), String)
Dim sColumn3 As String = TryCast(drTest("column3"), String)

Dim sTest1 As String = If(sColumn1.IsNotNullOrEmpty, sColumn1, String.Empty)
Dim sTest2 As String = If(sColumn2.IsNotNullOrEmpty, sColumn2, String.Empty)
Dim sTest3 As String = If(sColumn3.IsNotNullOrEmpty, sColumn3, String.Empty)
```

**Without ternary If**

```
Dim sTest1 As String = String.Empty
Dim sTest2 As String = String.Empty
Dim sTest3 As String = String.Empty

Dim sColumn1 As String = TryCast(drTest("column1"), String)
Dim sColumn2 As String = TryCast(drTest("column2"), String)
Dim sColumn3 As String = TryCast(drTest("column3"), String)

If sColumn1.IsNotNullOrEmpty Then sTest1 = sColumn1
If sColumn2.IsNotNullOrEmpty Then sTest2 = sColumn2
If sColumn3.IsNotNullOrEmpty Then sTest3 = sColumn3
```